Defining static IP addresses for different NIC adapters via Netplan
just wanted to ask you guys for a good template for netplan defined static IP address configuration for 2 separate NIC adapters (on Ubuntu 24.04 server).
Currently I have 1 interface configured for my private network with a default gateway, which is actually a bond and working fine. Now I would like to define another interface, which will be on different subnet and using a different gateway, and will be used for access to the internet.
So what would be the best practice (or at least working solution lol) to have this kind of private/public configuration? I've put up a sample config below for the new interface (enp16s0f0), but I am not quite sure about the correct value for "to:". Thanks in advance!
network:
  ethernets:
    enp11s0f0:
      dhcp4: false
    enp11s0f1:
      dhcp4: false
    enp16s0f0:
      addresses:
        - x.x.x.x/xx
      routes:
        - to: ???
          via: x.x.x.y
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
        search: []
    enp16s0f1:
      dhcp4: true
    enxe61f13ac52df:
      dhcp4: true
  bonds:
    bond:
      addresses: [z.z.z.z/zz]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: z.z.z.z
          metric: 100
      nameservers:
        addresses: []
        search: []
      interfaces:
        - enp11s0f0
        - enp11s0f1
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
  version: 2


What research and or effort have you done on this issue? Please post the config you have created and tried.

Hi, config I attempted is literally in the post. However, this way only 1 of the networks works - the one I define with a default gateway.

You need to define the subnet that this interface should be routed to and create a routing policy. For example:
enp16s0f0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.2/24
      dhcp4: no
      routes:
        - to: 192.168.1.0/24
          via: 192.168.1.1
          table: 101
      routing-policy:
        - from: 192.168.1.0/24
          table: 101
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
        search: []

More info can be found in the Netplan Documentation for How to configure source routing

You mention that the new interface will be used for the Internet and the existing interface is internal-only. Normally you would use the default route for the Internet, and list out the specific networks for your private interface.
